# Expand a summation with matlab as a function and write it to a text file

Tags: matlab

I have a function and I want to fit with a data set `(x,y)`:

```
E = exp(-a*R)*sum(c(i)*R^i) ,       i= 1,2 ,3 ...
```

`a` and `c` are variables. I want to fit with different `i`.

How can I expand this equation and use as a function in the following command? `lsqcurvefit(EQ,var,R,E)`

Also I want to write the expanded equation to a text file like the following example:

```
fprintf(fitting_text,' EQ     E(R)= exp(-a*R)*c1 *R;  \n');
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use the symbolic toolbox (create a `symfun` instead of a function handle) and use `subs` to substitue `i`

Answer (score 0):

A vectorized way of calculating the sum is to use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to build a [Vandermonde-like matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) with `R` and then perform a matrix-vector multiply:

```
sum = bsxfun(@power,R,1:k)*c(1:k);
```

It's not a computationally efficient as a loop, but it is nice and compact.

As for the function to pass to the fitting function, you can go one of two routes.
You can have `EQ` be a function of three arguments with the last one being the maximum power of `R` (Note that I have turned `a` into the last element of the parameter vector `c` and assumed everything is a column vector):

```
EQ = @(c,R,k) exp(-c(k+1)*R) .* ( bsxfun(@power,R,1:k)*c(1:k) );
c  = lsqcurvefit(@(c,R) EQ(c,R,3),var,R,E);  % cubic fit
```

You can also have `EQ` be a function of `k` only and return a function handle of arguments `c` and `R`:

```
EQ = @(k) @(c,R) exp(-c(k+1)*R) .* ( bsxfun(@power,R,1:k)*c(1:k) );
c  = lsqcurvefit(EQ(3),var,R,E);  % cubic fit
```

(I find this option more aesthetically pleasing).

An adaptive string can also be made using a function handle:

```
>> startOfLine = 'EQ    E(R) = exp(-a*R) * ';
>> str = @(k) [startOfLine,'(',strjoin(strcat({'c'},num2str((1:k)'),'*R^',num2str((1:k)')),' + '),')'];
>> str(3)
ans =
EQ    E(R)exp(-a*R) * (c1*R^1 + c2*R^2 + c3*R^3)
```